# Binding ConverterParameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Is there a way I could do this in a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="Visibility">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="Tag"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"
                Converter="{StaticResource AccessLevelToVisibilityConverter}"
                ConverterParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" />                        
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I simply need to send the `Tag` of top-level parent and the `Tag` of control itself to my converter class.

Answer (score 361, accepted):

The `ConverterParameter` property can not be bound because it is not a dependency property.

Since `Binding` is not derived from `DependencyObject` none of its properties can be dependency properties. As a consequence, a Binding can never be the target object of another Binding.

There is however an alternative solution. You could use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with a [multi-value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613613.aspx) instead of a normal Binding:

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="Visibility">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AccessLevelToVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                     AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The multi-value converter gets an array of source values as input:

```cs
public class AccessLevelToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.All(v => (v is bool && (bool)v))
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

No, unfortunately this will not be possible because `ConverterParameter` is not a `DependencyProperty` so you won't be able to use bindings

But perhaps you could cheat and use a `MultiBinding` with `IMultiValueConverter` to pass in the 2 `Tag` properties.

Answer (score 28):

There is also an alternative way to use `MarkupExtension` in order to use `Binding` for a `ConverterParameter`. With this solution you can still use the default `IValueConverter` instead of the `IMultiValueConverter` because the `ConverterParameter` is passed into the `IValueConverter` just like you expected in your first sample.

Here is my reusable `MarkupExtension`:

```
/// <summary>
///     <example>
///         <TextBox>
///             <TextBox.Text>
///                 <wpfAdditions:ConverterBindableParameter Binding="{Binding FirstName}"
///                     Converter="{StaticResource TestValueConverter}"
///                     ConverterParameter="{Binding ConcatSign}" />
///             </TextBox.Text>
///         </TextBox>
///     </example>
/// </summary>
```

```cs
[ContentProperty(nameof(Binding))]
public class ConverterBindableParameter : MarkupExtension
{
    #region Public Properties

    public Binding Binding { get; set; }
    public BindingMode Mode { get; set; }
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public Binding ConverterParameter { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public ConverterBindableParameter()
    { }

    public ConverterBindableParameter(string path)
    {
        Binding = new Binding(path);
    }

    public ConverterBindableParameter(Binding binding)
    {
        Binding = binding;
    }

    #region Overridden Methods

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
        Binding.Mode = Mode;
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(Binding);
        if (ConverterParameter != null)
        {
            ConverterParameter.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            multiBinding.Bindings.Add(ConverterParameter);
        }
        var adapter = new MultiValueConverterAdapter
        {
            Converter = Converter
        };
        multiBinding.Converter = adapter;
        return multiBinding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }

    #endregion

    [ContentProperty(nameof(Converter))]
    private class MultiValueConverterAdapter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

        private object lastParameter;

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (Converter == null) return values[0]; // Required for VS design-time
            if (values.Length > 1) lastParameter = values[1];
            return Converter.Convert(values[0], targetType, lastParameter, culture);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (Converter == null) return new object[] { value }; // Required for VS design-time

            return new object[] { Converter.ConvertBack(value, targetTypes[0], lastParameter, culture) };
        }
    }
}
```

With this `MarkupExtension` in your code base you can simply bind the `ConverterParameter` the following way:

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
<Setter Property="Visibility">
    <Setter.Value>
     <wpfAdditions:ConverterBindableParameter Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}"
                 Converter="{StaticResource AccessLevelToVisibilityConverter}"
                 ConverterParameterBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" />          
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Which looks almost like your initial proposal.

Comment: This is useful. However, `MultiValueConverterAdapter` is missing. I found it [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459958/Bindable-Converter-Converter-Parameter-and-StringF).

Comment: It does not work on Xamarin Forms because  multiBinding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) does not exist. Any alternative ?

Comment: try binding to DP: System.InvalidCastException:“Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type.

Comment: Worked exact like described in Framework 4.6.2. Great work