# WPF Binding Collection with Index

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm trying to use a collection that is a property of another collection to bind to a listbox. The following works fine

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations[0].Buildings}">
```

the problem is that I need a dynamic index and

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations[index].Buildings}">
```

where index is an integer in my viewmodel, does not work. Does anyone know how I can associate the index in my xaml with the property in my viewmodel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where index is an integer in my viewmodel, does not work. Does anyone know how I can associate the index in my xaml with the property in my viewmodel?

One simple option would be to just expose a `CurrentLocation` property within your ViewModel, which was effectively `Location[index]`.  You could then bind to it directly.

Comment: Yes I thought of this, just curious if there was another way without having to create another property with no other purpose than for binding. May very well end up being the solution though, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

A binding within a binding is not possible, So in XAML you can't bind to "index".

a. [Chris Moser's](http://www.wpftutorial.net/AttachedProperties.html) method, You can create a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) that binds to "index" Specify a change listener on the RegisterAttached handler and do your work there.

b. Use a Converter. You can provide index as the ConverterParameter

c. Bind to a POCO property. A POCO property would need its INotifyPropertyChanged signaled by the changer

Comment: b: You cannot bind to the index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter