# DataTemplate and WrapPanel visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, wrappanel

I'm getting this error:

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an
>   exception.

With xaml code:

```
 <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" >
    <WrapPanel.Visibility>
      <Binding Path="setVisible" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="{Binding setVisible}"/>
    </WrapPanel.Visibility>
                                         //textblocks goes here
  </WrapPanel>
```

and class:

```
public class dataTemplate_xItem
    {
        (...)
        public bool setVisible { get; set; }
        public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var flag = false;
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    flag = (bool)value;
                }
                else if (value is bool?)
                {
                    var nullable = (bool?)value;
                    flag = nullable.GetValueOrDefault();
                }
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    if (bool.Parse((string)parameter))
                    {
                        flag = !flag;
                    }
                }
                if (flag)
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var back = ((value is Visibility) && (((Visibility)value) == Visibility.Visible));
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)parameter)
                    {
                        back = !back;
                    }
                }
                return back;
            }
        }
    }
```

And before i'm adding item to ListView, checking

```
if(myValue != 0)
    newItem.setVisible = true;
else
    newItem.setVisible = false;
```

Any idea what goes wrong? :)

Comment: I see at least one thing that is wrong, bound `ConverterParameter`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/1021555) for details.

Answer (score 1):

icebat is correct. The ConverterParameter is not a DependencyProperty and therefore, cannot be bound to. Looking at your xaml, you do not need the ConverterParameter. Nor do you need the extended markup for the binding expression. You xaml can simply be

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Boolean2Visibility" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=setVisible, Converter={StaticResource Boolean2Visibility}}" />
```

This code assumes you are in a UserControl