# Wpf combobox selected item not working

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem

I have two object: UserDto and RoleDto. User has a property which is the RoleDto.
In my viewmodel I have the following:

```
public UserDto User
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            if (_user == value) return;

            _user = value;
            User.PropertyChanged += UserPropertyChanged;
            OnPropertyChanged("User");
        }
    }
    private UserDto _user;

public IEnumerable<RoleDto> Roles { get; set; } //I load all available roles in here
```

In the view, I want to select the role that the user belongs. This is how I define the combobox in the view:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}" SelectedItem="{Binding User.Role, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

If I try to create a new user and select a role from the combobox, it is correctly binded to the user. The problem is that when I load a user that already exists, the role is not displayed in the combobox (even the user has a role defined).

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what i infer , when you (userdto) user have data or not your combo-box binds to Roles . you must assign combobox selectedItem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the reference of `RoleDTO` that your `UserDTO` has, does not match any of the `RoleDTOs`  in  `Roles` collection which you set as `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox`.

Better define a property on your ViewModel like

```
    public RoleDTO SelectedRole
    {
        get { return Roles.FirstOrDefault(role => role.Role == User.RoleDto.Role); }
        set { User.RoleDto = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRole"); }
    }
```

and set it as SelectedItem of you combobox

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRole, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the second option on this page is the easiest way.

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/

You can override the equals property on your object so that it returns true if the items have the same data. Then when the combo box box goes to check to make sure your item is in the selection it will find a match.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to solve this problem is using `Converter` on `Binding`. when you use binding to bind `SelectedItem`, WPF will check the reference of `SelectedItem` against all objects inside `ItemsSource` property and of course if there was no match, `SelectedItem` will be empty. using `Converter` you can tell WPF that how it should match `SelectedItem`.
In this case you just need find `SelectedItem` among `ItemsSource` and return it to `Binding`. so follow these steps:
1- Create a class and implement `IValueConverter`. It has two methods: `Convert` and `ConvertBack`
2- for `Convert` method do something like this:

```
public class MySelecteItemBindingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var mySelectedItem = value as MySelectedItemType;
        var myItemsSource = parameter as List<MySelectedItemType>;
        var matchedItem = myItemsSource.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Id == mySelectedItem.Id);
        return matchedItem;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do just like Convert method
    }
}
```

3- Use this `Converter` on your `Binding` like this:

```
var myBinding = new Binding("YourBindingPath");
myBinding.Converter = new MySelectedItemBindingConverter();
myBinding.ConverterParameter = myItemsSource; //this is List<MySelectedItemType> in this example
myCombo.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, myBinding);
```

**Note**: if you want to do binding from `XAML` you can not pass `ConverterParameter` like this, instead you should create a `static` list and use that as `ItemsSource` or use `MultiBinding` to pass your `ConverterParameter` using a trick. here there is a good and simple explanation about it: [Binding ConverterParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter)

Comment: why down vote?!  if you have real reason to put a down vote, plz share it. tnx