# Pass Binding Name As Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF, is it possible to pass the name/path of the binding as a parameter? For example, say I have this:

```
<TextBox Width="300" Text="{Binding Path=Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Converter={x:Static local:AgeConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter={Binding ???}}" />
```

Is there anything I can put instead of the `???` so that the parameter value is "Age"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding ConverterParameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter)

Comment: What does that have to do with it? Read the question.

Comment: Could the phrase "The ConverterParameter property is not a dependency property and hence can not be bound." tell you something about it?

Comment: To make parameter value "Age" you should put ConverterParameter=Age. If you want something different, see Alessandro's link in first comment.

Comment: *What does that have to do with it? Read the question.*... wow, you're rude for someone who is asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alessandro mentionned, the `ConverterParameter` is not a `DependencyProperty` so it does't support data binding.

But since the `ConverterParameter` is a regular property of the `Binding` class, so you can set its value programmatically. You can do this in code:

```
var myTextBox = new TextBox();
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Age");
myBinding.ConverterParameter = "set this to anything you want";
myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

For example, you could change the value of `ConverterParameter` at a later time in an event handler to react to user input. The next time the binding is updated, it will call the `Converter` with the new `ConverterParameter`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myBinding.ConverterParameter = "a different converter parameter";
}
```