# Change string format on DataGridTextColumn cell based on value in other column, and keep values sortable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What I am trying to do is set the number of decimal places for a cell in one column, based on the corresponding row in another column. But I still need the first column to allow sorting after it has been converted.

The first thing I tried was using an IValueConverter. Here is the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <src:DataValueConverter x:Key="dataValueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Humidity" Binding="{Binding Humidity, Converter={StaticResource dataValueConverter}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Version}"></DataGridTextColumn>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>  
</Grid>
```

Here I want the number of decimal places in the humidity value based on the value in version. So I tried passing version to ConverterParameter, and then quickly discovered that it does not accept bindings.

I tried using MultiBinding with MultiValueConverter as suggested [Binding ConverterParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter). It did show the different decimal places, however the column could no longer be sorted. Also tried this bindable ConverterParameter http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/456589/Bindable-Converter-Parameter, giving the same results.

So is it possible to fill the ConverterParameter to get the desired results?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Humidity" Binding="{Binding Humidity, Converter={StaticResource dataValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=???}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to stick with MultiBinding, but also set the ***SortMemberPath*** for the humidity column. This tells the column what value to sort by. So the resulting XAML looks like:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Humidity" SortMemberPath="Humidity">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiDataValueConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Humidity" />
                        <Binding Path="Version" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Then, the code behind is an IMultiConverter, with something like:

```
public class MultiDataValueConverter: IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {                    
            int version = (int)(values[1]);

            string format = "0.0000";
            if(version==2)
            {
                format = "0.000000";
            }

            double val = (double)(values[0]);
            return val.ToString(format);            
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```