# Accessing binding context in Converter

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding

In a drawing application that allows user to add different objects like Rectangle, Ellipse, Text, Image etc, I have a "color box" that lets user see or change the fill of selected object(s). If there are multiple objects selected, I can't obviously show all, so I show the color of first selected object. When user changes the color of "color box", I want to change the fill of all selected objects. (That's also how VS properties window works btw)

How do I bind my "color box"'s `Brush` property (type `Brush`) to do this thing?

What I have already tried is this: I bind "color box"'s `Brush` property to selection object and then use a Converter that examines the selection object and if there is one or more objects in it, it returns the color of first selected object in `Convert()` function.

Problem however is that I have no way of implementing `ConvertBack()`, because it doesn't give me access to the selection object, so that I could iterate through the selected objects and assign them newly selected color.

Using `MultiBinding` is also of no use, as `value` parameter of `ConvertBack()` is a single object and doesn't give me access to the selection object. One idea was to supply selection object using `ConverterParameter`, but [ConverterParameter is not bindable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter).

Another idea (hack?) was to keep a class level variable to point to selection object and assign in `Convert()` function (by passing selection object in `MultiBinding`) and then use that variable in `ConvertBack()`, but I don't know how safe it is and whether `Convert()` and `ConvertBack()` will always be called in order.

So how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This turned out to be easier than I thought. For future readers, I simply added a property to my VM of `Brush` type (call it `SelectionBrush`) whose getter would return the `Brush` of first selected object, and whose setter would iterate through the entire selection and assign the Brush to appropriate objects (by checking their types). No more converters needed!