# Binding StringFormat to a binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can I bind `StringFormat` inside a `Binding` to another `Binding`?

```
Text="{Binding DeficitDollars, StringFormat=\{0:E6\}}"

Text="{Binding GNP, StringFormat={Binding LocalCurrencyFormat}}"
```

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `Binding` for `StringFormat`. As the exception tells you if you try it:

> A '`Binding`' can only be set on a `DependencyProperty` of a
>   `DependencyObject`

`StringFormat` is not a `DependencyProperty` and `Binding` is not a `DependencyObject`.

You can do these two things though.

1. **Setting it to a resource.**

You can define your different string formats in `App.xaml` in the `Resources` so they'll be reachable in the whole application:

```
<system:String x:Key="LocalCurrencyFormat">{0:C}</system:String>
```

`system` is `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

And then you can do:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDouble, StringFormat={StaticResource LocalCurrencyFormat}}" />
```

2. **Setting it to a static property of a class.**

You can have a class with all your different string formats:

```
public static class StringFormats
{
    public static string LocalCurrencyFormat
    {
        get { return "{0:C}"; }
    }
}
```

And use it in the `Binding` the following way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDouble, StringFormat={x:Static local:StringFormats.LocalCurrencyFormat}}" />
```

Comment: These are good patterns.  I was really looking for something more dynamic, where I could define the Formats in a Template and then pass info from my End-User XAML page into the template and there would be some logic.  I Think I can put that logic instead into a Converter in the Template.  Right now, App.xaml is sufficient, but I certainly see that becoming a maintenance nightmare as it becomes a clearinghouse for thousands of build-specific configuration parameters.  I'd rather tie to and have more dynamic capabilities of - the {Binding}-  to a Class or Template-Class or User-Control property.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Width="500" Height="500">

    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="LocalCurrencyFormat">Total: {0:C}</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeficitDollars, StringFormat=\{0:E6\}}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GNP, StringFormat={StaticResource LocalCurrencyFormat}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I suppose you can do this, but other answers are better because they define these constants externally.