# How to Pass IValueConverter Parameter?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In XAML, `<Grid x:Name="MainGrid3">`, Here I want to pass `MainGrid3` as a parameter of `IValueConverter`. How can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have `ConverterParameter` inside your binding, where you can use another binding with `ElementName` of your grid.

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid3"></Grid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBinding, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, 
           ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=MainGrid3}}"></TextBlock>
```

**Edit:** Ok, so apparently I was wrong, you can't use bindings inside ConverterParameter as it is not a dependency property. Working solution would be to use `x:Reference` like so:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid3"></Grid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBinding, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, 
           ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=MainGrid3}}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: "where you can use another binding with ElementName". Not true, because the `ConverterParameter` property of a Binding is not a dependency property, and hence can't be bound. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/1136211