# how to pass two data to IValueConterter(object vaue, object parameter)?

Tags: xaml, uwp

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtContentMessage" Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{Binding Entities,Converter={StaticResource ChangedColorToUrlConverter}}" MaxLines="3" Grid.Row="1">
</TextBlock>
```

Now, It just pass data to object value. So I also want to pass to object parameter

- object value will be assigned by Entities.
- object parameter will be assigned by Text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ConverterParameter` binding property

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtContentMessage" 
    Text="{Binding Text}" 
    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Foreground="{Binding Entities, ConverterParameter='PUT TEXT HERE', Converter={StaticResource ChangedColorToUrlConverter}}" 
    MaxLines="3" 
    Grid.Row="1" />
```

Comment: Foreground="{Binding Entities,ConverterParameter={Binding Text},Converter={StaticResource ChangedColorToUrlConverter}}"

Parameter is null

Comment: set the Mode of the binding. From the OP looked like you were referring to constant value. Made no mention of binding.

Comment: ,Mode=TwoWay-> it still is null

Comment: On both Text binding?

Comment: ConverterParameter={Binding Text}

It is a text

Comment: Set it on both other wise one won't know when the other changes. also you will need to let the bound Text property notify that Entities has changed in order for the binding to refresh and apply converter.

Comment: What you are tryign to achieve on the ConverterParameter cannot be done with binding http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/5233410

Comment: For example to me

Comment: Try doing it via multibinding. that looks promising.

Comment: On UWP doest support IMultiValueConverter