# Workaround for binding a property of type 'Binding' in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I'm attempting to bind the TargetNullValue of a TextBox *(inside a DataTemplate if that matters)* and of course getting the following error...

[image: Error message]

> "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'TargetNullValue' property of type
>   'Binding'"

because unlike UWP as shown in this [Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.targetnullvalue), WPF Binding Properties are not DependencyProperties.

Here's an oversimplification of the offending code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TargetFile, TargetNullValue={Binding Path=NullValue}}"/>
```

The `TargetFile` binding is declared exactly the same as `ValidationMask` so the issue is simply that `TargetNullValue` is not a DependencyProperty.

[There's an answer to another question with a `MultiBinding` workaround for getting multiple parameters in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/2043621) but I can't see how it could more generically map to `TargetNullValue` (plus `FallbackValue` and `ValidationMask` if you look at the full code below.)

---

Here's the full code in context (note the databindings that don't work are all replaced with `Wally[1-5]` so this version runs and shows "Wally" where it should have a binding):

```
<Style x:Key="FileSelectionBlockSet" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Prompt}" FontSize="11" Margin="0,0,0,-9" Background="{x:Null}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="FilePath" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TabIndex="4" Margin="6" Grid.Row="1">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="TargetFile" TargetNullValue="Wally1" FallbackValue="Wally2">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <ts:FileInfoToStringConverter/>
                                </Binding.Converter>
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <ts:StringIsValidFileRule ValidationMask="Wally3" MustExist="true" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                        <TextBox.ToolTip>
                            <Binding Path="ToolTip" TargetNullValue="Wally4" FallbackValue="Wally5" Mode="OneTime">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <ts:FileInfoNameToStringConverter/>
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.ToolTip>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" Content="Browse" Width="75" TabIndex="5" Margin="0,6,6,6" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Click="BrowseButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

And the C# for the items that are being assigned:

```
public class FileSelectionBlock
{
    public FileSelectionBlock(string prompt, string validationMask, string toolTip, DirectoryInfo startingDirectory = null, FileInfo targetFile = null)
    {
        Prompt = prompt;
        ValidationMask = validationMask;
        ToolTip = toolTip;
        StartingDirectory = startingDirectory;
        TargetFile = targetFile;
    }

    public string Prompt { get; set; }
    public string ValidationMask { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
    public FileInfo TargetFile { get; set; }
    public DirectoryInfo StartingDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Link that you posted is for UWP controls not standard controls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Data_BindingBase_TargetNullValue

Comment: The example that you're referring to is not WPF, but UWP, where Binding is derived from DependencyObject. In WPF, you can't bind the properties of a Binding.

Comment: @DipenShah This should be the answer.

Comment: @Clemens  Ok... That should be the answer. I agree the answer is nearly verbatim to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/2043621 but the question is quite different and I'd argue much better formed (although I'm biased.) I didn't vote to re-open because it's so on the edge.

Comment: The problem is still the same, you can't bind a Binding's properties.

Comment: @Clemens Ok, completely rewrote it taking into account the duplicate. I think it's viable at this point.

Comment: There's still nothing like a workaround. The only way to bind multiple inputs to a single output is a MultiBinding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179583/discussion-between-still-tony-and-clemens).