# WPF - How to bind Style's Setter to element's Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In, WPF, XAML, I have a Style that's being applied to the items of a ComboBox, I want to get the current item's Content Property but this doesn't seem to work:

```xml
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEditItem}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CrsNameCvtor}, ConverterParameter={Binding Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}}"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>
```

Comment: What is `dxe:ComboBoxEdit` ? Do you miss a library tag?

Comment: It's Devexpress's ComboBox, please think of it as WPF's default ComboBox.

Comment: And why is the Style defined inside the `Items` tag? That makes no sense.

Comment: I think you're right on that one! Should put in the Combobox directly I guess.

Comment: No, it belongs into `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: And you can't bind a Binding's ConverterParameter. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15309008/1136211

Comment: No, that's ok. What I'm trying to do is, I have the content in a format like: "abcd||stuf|stuff", and I'm trying to show it as only "abcd" while keeping the string intact in the VM

Comment: So the converter should just manipulate the Binding's source value? You don't need a ConverterParameter. Just take the `value` argument of the Convert method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197925/discussion-between-dan-and-clemens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Style should be assigned to the ComboBox's `ItemContainerStyle` property, and you don't need to set the Binding's ConverterParameter at all:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="dxe:ComboBoxEditItem">
        <Setter Property="Content"
                Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CrsNameCvtor}}"/>
    </Style>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemContainerStyle>
```