# How can I bind RotateTransform.Angle value via a Converter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding, rotatetransform, valueconverter

I need to create a Converter that takes some value and returns another. This will be used to set the textblock RotateTransform.Angle value in XAML.

If I hard-code the value to a static number the textblock gets rotated successfully. But when it goes through the converter it does not get rotated.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Hard-coded value (works):

```
<TextBlock ...

    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5">
        <RotateTransform.Angle>
            10
        </RotateTransform.Angle>
    </RotateTransform>
```

Going through a Converter (does not work):

```
<TextBlock ...

    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5">
        <RotateTransform.Angle>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RelativeToAbsoluteRotationConverter}">
                <Binding Path="RelativeAngle" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </RotateTransform.Angle>
    </RotateTransform>
```

Converter class:

```
public class RelativeToAbsoluteRotationConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Add logic here... Function is hit, but no rotation ever takes place.

        return 10; // irrelevant
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Why do you have a multibinding with just one binding? What's the logic you need?

Comment: If it works with a regular binding I'm fine, but I read that a ConverterParameter is not a dependency property, so multibinding is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter

Comment: @Andy: Basically the logic would be simple: The 'RelativeAngle' parameter is a value between 0 and 1. I need to map that to a new range of 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: What you are showing here should work. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: If you are always converting from [0..1] to [0..360] you won't need a second parameter...

Comment: Good news - I see a head start in the Output window: System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. Int32:'30' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'RotateTransform' (HashCode=57454947); target property is 'Angle' (type 'Double')

Comment: Ok, then you've got it: `return 10d;`. I would have sworn that automatic type conversion would take place after value conversion.

Comment: That's vaguely familiar that no implicit type conversion from a converter. The irony of it itches at the back of my memory.

Answer (score 0):

Output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. Int32:'30' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'RotateTransform' (HashCode=57454947); target property is 'Angle' (type 'Double')
```

The solution is to modify the `object Convert()` method and instead of returning an `int` (e.g. `10`), we return a `double` value (e.g. `10d` or `10.0`).

```
return 10d; // This works
```